# Update with new data in cache using key

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

I have a scenario in which if the user passes `Cache-Control : max-age=0` then I need to fetch data using the underlying service not from the cache. But I also then need to store this record in cache i.e update the cache. If the cacheControl is null or something else then fetch from cached data.

Currently I have

```
@Cacheable(key = "T(com.org.Utils).idKey(#id)",
  condition = "T(com.org.Utils).isCachingAllowed(#cacheControl)")
  public UserData get(String id, String cacheControl) {
      //Delegating to services and do the actual thing.
  }
```

So currently I am leaving it to the callie do a `cache.put(idKey(id), userData)`, which I feel is incorrect.

Is there a way to do this using annotation. I was looking at `@CachePut`
 but I think this won't help me here. Also using both is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@CachePut` does exactly what you want. Excerpt from the javadoc

> In contrast to the @Cacheable annotation, this annotation does not cause the advised method to be skipped. Rather, it always causes the method to be invoked and its result to be stored in the associated cache.

IMO, the error is put the logic of the `Cache-Control` down to the service. You need to extract that logic one level up and call the appropriate method.